# mysql performance, 300k rows, slow with index

Tags: mysql, database-performance

A table stores stock price data. Table d201405 stores all data in May 2014. Table includes symbol, day, price, volume. Indexed on (symbol, day). Around 300K rows in a table.

Simple select is slow. E.g.

```
select dayclose from d201405 where symbol = 'AAPL'
```

return around 20 rows, takes around 0.3s, and most of time is in sending data when showing the profile.

When I want to get 1 year data for charting, it takes several seconds, which is too slow for me. I believe this is a simple use, and with index, it should not take that long. But I cannot figure out the problem for a long time.

```
mysql> explain select id from d201405 where symbol = "GOOG";

+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | d201405 | ref  | symbol_day    | symbol_day | 13      | const |   27 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
```

SQL:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS d201405 (  `id` bigint( 20  )  NOT  NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`isin` varchar( 20  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `market` varchar( 10  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `symbol` varchar( 10  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `dayopen` float( 11, 4  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `dayhigh` float( 11, 4  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `daylow` float( 11, 4  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `dayclose` float( 11, 4  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `name` varchar( 255  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `sharesOutstanding` bigint( 20  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `dayvolume` bigint( 20  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `eps12monthttm` float( 10, 3  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `floatshares` bigint( 20  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `ma50` float( 10, 3  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `ma200` float( 10, 3  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `estimateY0` float( 10, 3  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `estimateY1` float( 10, 3  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `averageDailyVolume` bigint( 20  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `bookValue` float( 10, 2  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `dividendPerShare` float( 10, 2  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `epsQ1` float( 10, 2  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `changeWeek52High` float( 10, 2  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `week52Low` float( 10, 2  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `week52High` float( 10, 2  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `marketCapitalization` float( 20, 2  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `ebitda` float( 20, 2  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `changeWeek52Low` float( 10, 2  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `changeDay200MA` float( 10, 2  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `changeDay50MA` float( 10, 2  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `previousClose` float( 10, 2  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `priceSales` float( 10, 2  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `priceBook` float( 10, 2  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `PE` float( 10, 2  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `PEG` float( 10, 2  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `PEY0` float( 10, 2  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `PEY1` float( 10, 2  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `shortRatio` float( 10, 2  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `target1Y` float( 10, 2  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `dividendYield` float( 10, 2  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `day` tinyint( 4  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
  `actual` float( 10, 2  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `estimate` float( 10, 2  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `rev` double  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `revest` double  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `TotRevisions` tinyint( 4  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `TotTargetRevisions` tinyint( 4  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `AvgTargetRevisions` float  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `adjclose` float( 11,4 )  DEFAULT NULL ,
 `exdividend` date DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY  KEY (  `id`  ) ,
 UNIQUE  KEY  `symbol_day` (  `symbol` ,  `day`  )  ) ENGINE  =  MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET  = latin1;
```

Here is the profiling result

```
mysql> show profile;
+--------------------------------+----------+
| Status                         | Duration |
+--------------------------------+----------+
| starting                       | 0.000034 |
| checking query cache for query | 0.000066 |
| Opening tables                 | 0.000016 |
| System lock                    | 0.000009 |
| Table lock                     | 0.000032 |
| init                           | 0.000030 |
| optimizing                     | 0.000014 |
| statistics                     | 0.152840 |
| preparing                      | 0.000039 |
| executing                      | 0.000007 |
| Sending data                   | 0.811723 |
| end                            | 0.000025 |
| query end                      | 0.000007 |
| freeing items                  | 0.000047 |
| storing result in query cache  | 0.000012 |
| logging slow query             | 0.000006 |
| cleaning up                    | 0.000007 |
+--------------------------------+----------+
```

Update: Is it possible that the problem is due to interleaving? The first 15000 rows is for day 1, and second 15000 rows is for day 2. Then when select by symbol, database needs 30 read hits to get the 30 rows?

Comment: 1. Complete table schema 2. `EXPLAIN` 3. How big (in terms of relative and absolute number of rows and size in Kb) the result set is?

Comment: Try explain mysql query..

Comment: is `select id from d201405 where symbol = "GOOG"` the query that returns 1 year of data?

Comment: To return 1 year of data, I will run 12 selects. Each select takes around 0.3s. Add together, it spends 4-5 seconds.

Comment: You could try using a hash-index or clustered (on just the symbol), but both would require you to use InnoDB instead of MyISAM

Comment: @dfb Why? Could you explain in details?

Comment: @Tony - InnoDB doesn't support these.  It's not clear why this is taking so long, though. You're using a profiler or just eyeballing it with the 0.3 seconds?

Comment: Will you provide `EXPLAIN` finally or are we supposed to continue guessing?

Comment: you'll find useful advice on http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/white-papers/mysql-and-hadoop-guide-to-big-data-integration/

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed my guessing. The problem is due to the scattering of the data. That means, to retrieve n records, the disk are hit by n times. Assume the time for one access is 10 ms, then retrieving 30 rows needs 0.3s. To solve the problem, I re-order the table by symbol, so when retrieving price data for a symbol, only one disk access is required, since these records are in the same disk page.